# "You have an error in your SQL syntax" при выполнении запроса на INSERT

Tags: mysql

Выполняю и говорит такую ошибку

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_ago (user_id,time) VALUES ('".$row['id']."','".$date."'") or die('Error #6435464<br>'.mysql_error());
```

Что может быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это, как и сказано, неправильный синтаксис:

```
INSERT INTO user_ago (user_id,tiime) VALUES ('1234'),'2013-03-01'
```

Comment: вот я и обращаюсь, у меня date целое число (1362093788) и user_id и в бд тоже указаны, то что они int

Comment: При чём тут типы данных? Здесь неправильный синтаксис самого запроса, должно-то быть:

    INSERT INTO user_ago (user_id,tiime) VALUES ('1234','2013-03-01')

Comment: т.е '".$date."' нельзя?

Comment: И теперь закрывающую скобку забыли.

Comment: Можно, только скобку надо перенести

Comment: всё, точно не заметил